# Error while restoring packages after update

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, backup

I am fairly new to Linux use and I recently upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. I followed some advise [here](https://ostechnix.com/backup-installed-packages-and-restore-them-on-freshly-installed-ubuntu-system/) to create a tar file to backup the installed packages and then restore them after the upgrade.

I created this file: **apt-clone-state-ubuntuserver.tar.gz** under **~/mypackages** directory, using:
`$ sudo apt-clone clone ~/mypackages`

I have now tried to restore the packages, using this command: `$ sudo apt-clone restore apt-clone-state-ubuntuserver.tar.gz`

However, I am getting these errors, and not able to extract the files:

> WARNING:root:can't add libevent-2.1-6 (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
> WARNING:root:can't add libevent-core-2.1-6 (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
> WARNING:root:can't add libexpat1 (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
> WARNING:root:can't add libexpat1-dev (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
> WARNING:root:can't add libext2fs2 (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)

Does anyone know how to get around this and extract the files?

Comment: You are attempting to install a bunch of 18.04 packages onto your 20.04 system, and apt is correctly and properly refusing to do so. You have mis-used apt-clone for a purpose it is not designed. A "get around" might break your system quite horribly. Use 20.04 packages on a 20.04 system. Advice: Look at your list of packages in your tarball. Install 20.04 versions of each. If you have special settings or configurations, you can cherry-pick those out of the tarball.

Comment: Thank you. Will try that. Ya, there is a version conflict.